# Nutch 2.3.1 seeding with rest API

Tags: rest, nutch, seeding

So I've got a Nutch 2.3.1 install, I don't think it matters but it's using Hbase and Elastic search.

I'm trying to use the rest api to insert seeds and have nutch server running on port 8081. If I sent a get /admin I will recieve a response to the server is running but when I try to do /seed/create with the payload
{
   "id":"12345",
   "name":"test",
   "seedUrls":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "seedList":null,
         "url":"http://test.website.co.uk"
      }
   ]
}

I get an error 500. I've not been able to find any alternative syntax online that works, if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.